# Is it possible to load details in the textfield via AutoComplete method in Struts2-jQuery editable Grid?

Tags: jquery, struts2

How can i load the details of an ItemCode as Auto complete method when typing in the textfield of Struts2-jQuery Editable Grid? Can I customize the Struts2-jQuery Editable Grid?

Like 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data

Answer (score 0):

If you like the example you provided why don't you just do it that way?

Very few people are capable of answering your question because someone has wrapped a tag library around tool which is meant to be manipulated with JS.  Ajax tag libraries are just a bad idea.

There are many good JS/jQuery grids.  Many here can help you learn how to use the struts2-json-plugin which will let you create your own ajax calls and in the end allow you can do anything with any of the UI jquery UI components you can think of.